# How can I display reviews related to a profile?

Tags: views, users

I have tried everything I can think of but can not solve this. I would sooo much appreciate any help with the following:
I am using Drupal 7., latest Version. For displaying user details, I am using Profile2. In order to allow other users to give feedback about a member, I have installed the Reply Module, set up a reply bundle, and a reply type called Recommend. Recommend itself has two fields. I guess it is a form. I have embedded this in the profile page and it nicely displays on the View page of each member's profile. Reply has a reply-entity_id which is the same as the profile_id of the profile from which a reply has been created. Lets say a member submits a reply on the view page of another members profile with the profile_id 7. The reply will get the reply-entity_id 7.

I am trying to display the replies each member received from other members using Views (content panes).

However, I cannot separate the replies a member has created from the replies he has received. For days I am trying to make a relationship between UID and reply entity id or pass arguments from the URL to pick up the entity id. I have tried using EVA, content panes, entity references. Could anyone please let me know how I can achieve that the view displays only reply entity id created on a specific profile (both IDs are the same as explained above). Hope this makes sense. Many thanks in advance.